# How to use sass variables in css attribute selectors like [class^="$variables"]?

Tags: css, sass

```
@mixin fullwidth($breakpoint,$grid-size)
{
    $varGridsize:col-#{$grid-size};
    @media only screen and (max-width: #{$breakpoint}px) { 
        [class ^="$varGridsize"]{width:100%;}
    }
}
```

how can we addd a variable in  this  `[class ^="$varGridsize"]` selector it is treating it as a string and returning a string in css file as

```
[class^="$varGridsize"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply wrap `$varGridsize` in `#{}` like:

```
@mixin fullwidth($breakpoint,$grid-size){
    $varGridsize:col-#{$grid-size};
    @media only screen and (max-width: #{$breakpoint}px){ 
       [class ^="#{$varGridsize}"]{width:100%;}
    }
}
```

Comment: It's called interpolation http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Interpolation_____